# as3 xml.replace syntax calling

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, replace, e4x

I need to know how to use xml.replace.

Here is my code:

```
             myXML.replace("WHAT DO PUT HERE?", <p>testing</p>);
             trace(myXML);
```

I need to change the Titles of choice1 and choice2 etc.
How do I call them using xml.replace?

Here is the XML:

```
<SETTINGS>
  <Settings Title="choice1">Home</Settings>
  <Settings Title="choice2">Options</Settings>
</SETTINGS>
```

Finally, how would I save this new edited file and  pass it thru a function I have?

The function below does not work. I can not pass the xml to the function and the
stream.write is expecting a string, I think.

```
public function saveSettings(daFile:XML)
        {
            stream.open(someFile, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes(daFile);
            trace("Settings SAVED!");
            stream.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, `XML.replace` isn't a proper choice in this case, it will replace all `Settings` nodes. You can use this more forward solution:

```
    var xml:XML = <SETTINGS>
          <Settings Title="choice1">Home</Settings>
          <Settings Title="choice2">Options</Settings>
        </SETTINGS>;

    trace("before\n", xml);
    xml.Settings.(@Title == "choice1").* = "Home2";
    xml.Settings.(@Title == "choice2").* = "Options2";

    trace("after\n", xml);
```

outpout:

```
before
 <SETTINGS>
  <Settings Title="choice1">Home</Settings>
  <Settings Title="choice2">Options</Settings>
</SETTINGS>
after
 <SETTINGS>
  <Settings Title="choice1">Home2</Settings>
  <Settings Title="choice2">Options2</Settings>
</SETTINGS>
```

Comment: BAM! Exactly it! Do you recommend i change the question to help those who are searching for this same solution? Or should I keep it as is so they might search for what I was and find your answer?

Comment: I have one more question related to this. I made an edit in the top question.

Comment: I added it as a full question here. Its a tricky one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201099/as3-urlrequest-and-file-stream-saving-xml-data-error-3013-file-or-directory